# setting debug="false" in web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am having this problem if i set debug=false in web.config file.

i had a treeview where all the nodes are loaded dynamically from code pagehide during `Page_Load` event

if i set `debug="true"` this works fine if i add another node form a button and so on.

But if i set it to false. nodes are loaded correctly during `If Not IsPostBack Then` if i add a new node, it will show correctly but if there is another postback,the newly added button will be disappeared and data are loaded from the first postback and i have to close the web and reopen again to load the new nodes to load.

the data will always remains at the first postback if i set debug to false.
anyone know why i am not getting new data from subsequent postback instead of first postback if i set debug to false?

please take note that i only having this issue on internet explorer 11. chrome and firefox i does not have this issue .
below is my code

```
  If Not IsPostBack Then
        Try
            masternode = New TreeNod
            masternode.Text = "Scale Management"
            masternode.Value = "-4"
            sendscalenodes.Nodes.Add(masternode)
            loadNodes()'load all nodes on pageload

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btndepadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndepadd.Click
 'add nodes code here
 loadNodes()'reload all nodes to refresh the tree view
End Sub

    Sub loadNodes()
    DepGr1.Nodes.Clear()
    dbconnection.connect()
    masternode = New TreeNod
    masternode.Text = "Data Management"
    masternode.Value = "Data Management"
    masternode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None
    DepGr1.Nodes.Add(masternode)
    Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim dr2 As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim sql2 As String = Nothing

    sql = "select * from [data group] where DG_parent=-3"
    dr = dbconnection.dr(sql)
    Do While dr.Read
        parentnod = New EleapTreeNod
        parentnod.Text = dr.Item(4)
        parentnod.Value = dr("DG_ID")
        DepGr1.Nodes.Add(parentnod)

        sql2 = " select * from [data group] where DG_parent=" & dr.Item(0) & ""
        dr2 = dbconnection.dr(sql2)
        Do While dr2.Read
            childnod = New EleapTreeNod
            childnod.Text = dr2.Item(4)
            childnod.Value = dr2("DG_ID")
            parentnod.ChildNodes.Add(childnod)

        Loop
        dr2.Close()

    Loop

    dr.Close()

    dbconnection.ConClose()

    DepGr1.ExpandAll()
End Sub
```

Comment: can you check if there is any exception thrown please? that empty catch make it hard to figure that one out and show us the loadnodes() code

Comment: nope there isn't any exception thrown and nodes are loading fine with debug='true' . i updated the loadnodes code. thanks

Comment: if you put break point in loadnodes() does it retrieve anything? does all the code that add nodes get actually hit?

Comment: i am having issue like this,just that i had all my viewstates enabled. and only happened in internet explorer.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asgoyal/archive/2012/08/29/asp-net-view-state-enableviewstate-vs-viewstatemode.aspx
Fredou:yes all get hits. i debug them line by line before. all went well and dataare shown correctly. only new nodes are not shown on second second postback